# How to use ''SpotifyiOS" framework and Authorize app without acutally playing a song

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I am using 'SpotifyiOS' framework recommended by Spotify (https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk) to access their APIs. To login/Authorise the App we must login to Spotify and it is invoked by following available methods:

[image: appRemote.authorizeAndPlayURI(..]

where `appRemote` is an instance of `SPTAppRemote`

It plays a song even if I pass empty `String` as `URI` as shown below:

[image]

How can I authorise app without playing any song using 'SpotifyiOS' famework?

Comment: https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/auth.md

Comment: Thanks @JoachimIsaksson can you put that as an answer so that I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SPTSessionManager](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/auth.md) to authenticate without playing a song.

The flow is a bit more convoluted and better followed at the documentation link than copy/pasted here, but in short you configure the SPTSessionManager and provide it a delegate that on successful authentication provides a token to your SPTAppRemote which can then be used to control the application.